# Typescript Get type of "import * as whatIsMyType from './foo';"

Tags: typescript

My `foo.ts` exports several functions with same signature e.g. `(a: number): number`.

In my main.ts, I do

```
import * as foo from './foo';
// foo.myFunction1 and foo.myFunction2 are defined

export const resultsFor = (a: number) => {
  return Object.keys(foo).reduce(
      (result, currentKey) => {
        result[currentKey] = foo[currentKey](a);
        return result;
      },
      {} as {[index:string]: number}
    );
}
```

Now the type of `resultFor` is `(a: number): {[index:string]: number}`, but that's slightly too generic.

I wish `resultFor`'s type to be

```
(a: number): {myFunction1: number, myFunction2: number, /* and other exports from 'foo.ts': number */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do with mapped types and `keyof`. Consider the following:

```
type fooKey = keyof typeof foo;
export const resultsFor = (a: number) => {
    return Object.keys(foo).reduce(
        (result, currentKey) => {
            result[currentKey as fooKey] = foo[currentKey as fooKey](a);
            return result;
        },
        {} as {[index in fooKey]: number}
    );
}
```

Here, we're using explicit type assertions, since we know that elements of `Object.keys` are always of the type stated; and this type (essentially a union of all possible function names) becomes the index type of the return value.

Comment: Thanks! Creating a `type FooMap = {[index in fooKey]: number};` works, but not `interface FooMap {[index in fooKey]: number};` Is there a reason for that?